# If I start today, what hardware need to develop for iOS

Tags: ios, macos, app-store

I read some questions about it, but some are old and with the recent ios 7 this can be a little different. I usually develop android, and I have opportunity to port my apps to iOS, but I havent a mac or ipad/iphone etc..

Ok, I was thinking to buy a used mac-mini, and a new ipadmini retina, but, I dont know how used mac mini can affect to my developments, I only need a mac to upload and sign the apps, I develop all using a framework on windows.

Can I buy a old mac mini? It's compatible? I havent anybody can help me with this. Thanks a lot.

Sorry my english.

Comment: this is not a question to be asked here! Better for u that read first about how-to-ask section of this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All this information is available on Apple's developer site http://developer.apple.com/

But in a nutshell, you need a Mac running an Intel processor and OS X 10.9 or later. Any Mac Mini a few years old should be able to do this..

Comment: Thanks! I read on apple's developer site but not found information concrete for old macs, and dont know that versions can run the macs.. Sorry for the off-topic question.

Comment: Xcode 5 is required for iOS 7 development! Go to https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action and read all the articles you can...